# Event delegation works with document but not with parents

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML code, and i am currently trying to add the 'selected' class when a photo is clicked, and to remove the class when it is clicked again.

```
<div id="container">
      <h1>Photo Gallery</h1>

      <div id="gallery">
        <div class="photo">
          <img src="photos/skyemonroe.jpg">
          <div class="details">
            <div class="description">The Cuillin Mountains, Isle of Skye, Scotland.</div>
            <div class="date">12/24/2000</div>
            <div class="photographer">Alasdair Dougall</div>
          </div>
        </div>

       //Repetitions of the photo class.....

      </div>
      <a id="more-photos" href="pages/1.html">More Photos</a>
</div>
```

I am currently using the following jquery code to bind an event handler to the photo's ancestor so that when more pictures are appended to the page when clicking the more photos button, the jquery code will still work with these newly added pictures.

jQuery

```
 $('#gallery').on('click','.photo',function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  });
```

The jQuery code above **DOES NOT** work when i try using the #gallery, **NOR** does it work when i try using #container.However, the code works when i use $(document) for the event delegation.

I can't seem to figure out why binding the event handlers to the parent elements do not work, but binding it to the document itself makes it work.

Would appreciate any insights into the matter

EDIT: Added the jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/744cX/ ( The code works in the fiddle, but does nothing on my laptop, and i can't seem to figure out why)

Comment: Add more relevant code add a  jsfiddle

Comment: @kenneth: can you share the code that is changing the content.

Comment: @Dave and @ Milind Anantwar i've added the fiddle, and the code works in the fiddle, but isn't working on my computer...

Comment: If it works in the fiddle then the js code is fine.  The only thing in js that could stop the delegation working is if you replace the element the delegation is bound to.  Check your other HTML - have you got a mismatched `div`or something?  Sometimes this confuses the browser about what is inside what and messes up the delegation.

Comment: Does the toggle code work *before* you click next page or not?

Comment: I've checked the html and there isn't any mismatched div, and the toggle code does not work even before i click next page when i'm using #container and #gallery.

Comment: Is the entire gallery added dynamically or is it present when the page fiorst loads?

Comment: There are a few images when the page first loads, and more pages are added dynamically later

Comment: IS the delegated event set in a document ready? (in your actual code, not the fiddle)?  What I am getting at is does `#gallery` exist on the page at the point you set the events on it?  Do you have only one item with id "gallery"?  If it works in the fiddle then soemthing else with your page must be breaking it.  Your principle approach is right.

Answer (score 0):

I forked your fiddle and as can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/6Qz8C/1/

```
$('#gallery').on('click','.photo',function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

I did:

- when the `nextpage` event is fired, append a new photo.
- add the event delegation when the document is ready.
- set the delegator to the `#gallery`

Answer (score 0):

You can listen event on '.photo' class

```
<div class="photo" onclick="$(this).toggleClass('selected');">
```

Comment: No, because the OP is adding photos dynamically.  So .on is better than .lcik since .click only finds those present at the point you bind the event

Comment: ok. So you can add attribute onclick="$(this).toggleClass('selected');" in html

Comment: You *can*.  But why?  You can run a new `$().click(function(){})` on the new elements when you add them (better than iinline onclick imo).  But it's usually better to use event delegation and have the event code in only one place.

Comment: You can add event listener in callback if $.get() complete.
Make addEventPhoto = function(){ //listener event};

Comment: Yes, you *can*.  I said that in my comment ("You can run a new `$().click(function(){}`) on the new elements when you add them").  But delegation is generally better in this situation since it allows you to set up all your events in one place in document ready.  Makes the code cleaner and more maintainable.